# Selenium difference in cookies headless

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote the following code:

```
def retrieve_cookies(self):
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True

        # Create driver based on 'geckodriver.exe', keep in mind that the Linux driver should be downloaded for Linux OS'
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='api/common/geckodriver.exe')
        driver.get("https://betwinner.com/us/")

        # Wait 3 seconds to load the home page of BetWinner
        sleep(5)

        # Find and CLick 'Login' button
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('loginDropTop_con').click()

        # Populate form
        driver.find_element_by_id('auth_id_email').send_keys('')
        driver.find_element_by_id('auth-form-password').send_keys('')

        # Submit form
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('auth-button').click()

        # Wait 5 seconds to complete the login process
        sleep(5)

        # Store cookies in dict
        self.cookies = { c["name"]: c["value"] for c in driver.get_cookies() }

        # Close browser, it is not needed anymore
        driver.quit()
```

When running this code headfull I get the following cookies back from it:

```
{'auid': 'XXX', '_ym_uid': 'XXX', '_ym_d': '1597607874', 'ggru': '195', 'bonus_choice': '0', 'blocks': '1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1', 'completed_user_settings': 'true', '_ym_isad': '2', '_gat_gtag_UA_131605460_1': '1', 'sh.session_be98639c': '307cda20-b806-42a8-93b4-9027bcbb7740', 'SESSION': 'XXX', 'tzo': '2', 'ua': '208765015', 'uhash': 'bfad09b6f9bff01beb35cb97afc9ebee', 'cur': 'EUR', 'activeid': '208765015', 'act': '00000101', 'asia_view': '0', 'coefview': '0', 'indicator': '1', 'typeBetNames': 'short', 'compact_vid_off': '0', 'lite_version': '0', 'is_rtl': '1', 'disable_line_express': '0', 'disable_live_express': '0', 'colorChange': '0', 'autoSummSel_off': '0', 'only_betting': '0', 'show_number_game': '0', 'font_size': 'f-s_normal', 'new_view_score': 'false', 'new_view_custom_group_765': 'false', 'extended_scores_dashboard_off': '0', 'game_cols_count': '2', 'show_popup_lucky_wheel': '0', 'hide_slider_top_games': '0', 'coupon_logo': '0', 'statistic_in_modal': '0', 'when_change_coef': '2', 'automax': 'false', 'is_goldenbet_enabled': '0', 'side_video_setting': '0', 'disallow_sport': '', '_glhf': '1597625662', 'right_side': 'right', 'visit': '2-88a257be578fab42c494b98bc8258a81', '_ym_visorc_48347336': 'w', '_ga': 'GA1.2.132738407.1597607874', '_gid': 'GA1.2.1426998216.1597607874', 'lng': 'us', 'flaglng': 'us'}
```

And when I run it headless I get the following cookies:

```
{'SESSION': 'XXX', 'visit': '1-b9f9fcb79e68312cefda00309791dc7e', 'typeBetNames': 'full', 'coefview': '0', 'indicator': '1', 'auid': 'U5PMHF85j/BU9ItIBRDoAg==', 'tzo': '2', 'ggru': '223', '_ym_uid': '1597607925529773283', '_ym_d': '1597607925', 'bonus_choice': '0', 'blocks': '1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1', 'completed_user_settings': 'true', '_ym_isad': '2', '_ga': 'GA1.2.1486114340.1597607927', '_gid': 'GA1.2.18345131.1597607927', '_ym_visorc_48347336': 'w', '_gat_gtag_UA_131605460_1': '1', 'sh.session_be98639c': 'a721d0cc-2726-497d-8f90-4ca05f9b99a1', 'lng': 'us', 'flaglng': 'us', '_grant_1597625695': 'ay3767122', '_glhf': '1597625711'}
```

How can I get the same cookies running the browser headless as when I run it headfull?

Comment: Hey, did you solved this issue?